# Yoast SEO : Page not found in HOMEPAGE

Tags: seo, wordpress

I've just installed on my wordpress site Yoast SEO, and for each page I've this :

`%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%`

In the home page I have this error, it means : **PAGE NOT FOUND**

[image: Home page]

It's not able to found the page title, but isn't a page, it's just a php file writted by me, so someone knows how to put the right title , just : **HOME** for the HOMEPAGE

For each page it works :

[image]

P.S. : In homepage the page 's loading correctly. I want only the correct title

Comment: If it is powered by a PHP page that you wrote, you should just be able to put `<title>` tags in yourself, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's just a php file writted by me

Yoast SEO plugin works for Wordpress generated pages and since you are expecting it to generate appropriate title for a custom file written by you, it won't work.

> so someone knows how to put the right title , just : HOME for the HOMEPAGE

For the php file written by you, simple throw in the HTML tags, and you should be good to go!